# Whenever I am trying to create a Reacjs project with CRA it hangs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to make a create project with create-react-app but it hangs. I have tried to clear the cache but still, it hangs.

One strange thing is there that there is a .staging file inside node_modules and inside that .staging there are all the dependencies
I have also attached the screenshot of the terminal execution[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use PowerShell instead of MINGW. PowerShell runs natively on Windows and solves many performance and stability issues.

Comment: I am using git-bash

Comment: Use PowerShell instead of git-bash

Comment: One strange thing is there that there is a .staging file inside node_modules and inside that .staging there are all the dependencies